# 'ValueError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

Tags: pcap, dpkt

While using dpkt to parser a UDP pcap file, got the following error message:

```
with open('file.pcap', 'rb') as fopen:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(fopen)
for timestamp, buf in pcap:
    print (timestamp)
```

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: read of closed file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'ValueError' object has no attribute '*render_traceback*'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is automatically closed when leaving the `with open(...) ...` block:

```
with open('file.pcap', 'rb') as fopen:
    # still open here
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(fopen)
    
# automatically closed here
for timestamp, buf in pcap:
    print (timestamp)
```

Thus, you need to put your pcap reading into the same block where the file was opened:

```
with open('file.pcap', 'rb') as fopen:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(fopen)
    for timestamp, buf in pcap:
        print (timestamp)
```